# How to scrape data from web page, after manipulation on client side, faster then phantom js does?

Tags: web-scraping, phantomjs

I need to scrape some data from web page, but first I need to do some interactions, and after client recalculates values - scrape it.
I've tried phantom.js, but it takes about 20s to finish this. 
Maybe there are faster tool, or another approach to do it? To be honest I'am not very familiar with phantom.js, so maybe I missed something. Will be glad to get advice and some links to good material, about how to implement that functionality in right way. Thank you.

Comment: Can you *not* use a headless browser and do calculation on the server? Can you use not a real headless browser but a library like jsdom?  What is the site? What is your approach to scraping it (aka show the code)?

Comment: Yeap, I wasn`t clear.
The site is - https://www.tradingview.com/markets/cryptocurrencies/prices-all/

I need to scrape data from "Trend-Followind" tab. Of course first of all I checked network and found a route to get initial data. But problem is, all calculations happened on client side, and as you can see, when tab changed - there are no changes in url, so I can just get needed info.

Comment: The most cleanest way in this situation is investigate how these values calculated. I found formulas in minified file, but I can't figure out what each variable in formula mean. I also wrote topics on forums to figure out how that things calculated, but there were not clear answers. I spend a lot of time and now I want to change my approach to solving this situation.

Comment: Okay, so it's probably better to scrape from a client. Without seeing the code it's impossible to give advice on optimization. Also: 20s. Is it indeed a long time if the job gets done? Do you need to scrape thousands of data items in an hour or maybe just once a day?

Comment: Yeap, probably it is not so big problem. I am trying puppeteer now, maybe it will have better results.

Comment: I mean I don't know anything about your code, maybe you're making hard-coded pauses of 3 seconds waiting for scripts to load :) so to improve the script you should show it first!